# Searching for infromation out of a database using text input c#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to search for a customers "forename", "surname", and "customerid" to show into a combo box through the use of sql.

```
     string strSql = "SELECT customerID&\" \" & forename &\" \" & surname AS FullName, surname FROM customer WHERE [customerID]='" + txtCustomerID.Text +"'";
```

Though with this code I get a "data mismatch exception" which I'm assuming is because I'm using a string and searching for an int?

Comment: **Never** use string concatenations to build SQL queries. This code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Always use parametrized queries to avoid meeting with [`boby-tables`](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: [How do Parameterized queries help against SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

just change this: You dont need to use the '' because its an int

string strSql = @"SELECT customerID +'\' + forename + '\' + surname AS FullName, surname FROM customer WHERE [customerID]=" + txtCustomerID.Text;

But as other have told you this is not a good practice to use string concatenations to build SQL queries, and more if its with parameters or data that you get from the users.

Comment: now im getting this error "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[CustomerID]='"

Comment: Are you sure its & and not + for concatenation?

Comment: both + and & give me the same exception unfortuntally :/

Comment: @Bunion, try this:  SELECT customerID, forename + \" \"+surname AS FullName, surname FROM customer;  If it works, you only need to change your query so that it uses the parameter object for the where clause

Comment: I just edited my awnser please try it out and let us know how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone says; do not construct queries from text fields, use a parameterized query:

```
SqlCommand sqlQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT customerID, forename + ' ' + surname AS FullName FROM customer WHERE customerID = @customerID", sqlConnection);
sqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", Int32.Parse(txtCustomerID.Text));
```

You might also want to do some error-checking on `txtCustomerID.Text`.