# Updating sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update

hi im trying to update points from a windows from to a database, but im not sure how i get the infromation from a variable "totalPoints" to be inserted into the "points" field from the database

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strCon))
        {
            String sqlPoints = "UPDATE points FROM customer WHERE [customerID]="
            + txtCustomerID.Text;
            conn.Open();


            conn.Close();
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you should be using parameterized queries - this is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Take a look here: [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

To answer your question, you need to look into `OleDbCommand` and `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```
public void InsertRow(string connectionString, string insertSQL)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        // inserts a new row in the source table.
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(insertSQL);

        // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection(v=vs.100).aspx

Also, you might need to relook at your SQL -- not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  If you're using SQL Server, the syntax should look like `UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = VALUE WHERE FIELD = VALUE`.

Good luck.

Comment: ok thanks il change it to a parameterized query! how do i make it update a field thats allread in the table e.g. from 0 - 25?

Comment: This what you mean: UPDATE customers SET points = 25 WHERE customerid = 1