# Using text values in query

Tags: c#, sql

It seems that I am an idiot, trying to perform a simple query to a SQL database in C#.
This is the query, I am trying to execute:

```
 _query = "SELECT PC.SN, User.Name + ' ' + User.Family as AssignedTo " +  
          "FROM PC LEFT JOIN Users ON PC.USERID = Users.ID " + 
          "WHERE PC.Type = '" + AssetTypeCB.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

The problem is that I am getting a "cannot call methods on nvarchar" error message.
Do you have any idea what might be the issue?

Comment: Good sample of SQL injection. :)

Comment: for evangelisation purpose: use parametrized queries.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection for why the above comments are good ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query seems wrong. You need to change `User.Name` to `Users.Name`, et al. The correct query would be:

```
 _query = "SELECT PC.SN, Users.Name + ' ' + Users.Family as AssignedTo " +
          "FROM PC LEFT JOIN Users ON PC.USERID = Users.ID " + 
          "WHERE PC.Type = '" + AssetTypeCB.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

---

Also, allow me to suggest using parameterized queries for your code. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) can tell you why you should.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and guidance. It is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to add parameters to the query

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class ParamDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // conn and reader declared outside try
        // block for visibility in finally block
        SqlConnection conn   = null;
        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        string inputCity = "London";

        try
        {
            // instantiate and open connection
            conn =  new 
                SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI");
            conn.Open();

            // don't ever do this
            // SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            // "select * from Customers where city = '" + inputCity + "'";

            // 1. declare command object with parameter
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "select * from Customers where city = @City", conn);

            // 2. define parameters used in command object
            SqlParameter param  = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@City";
            param.Value         = inputCity;

            // 3. add new parameter to command object
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            // get data stream
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // write each record
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", 
                    reader["CompanyName"], 
                    reader["ContactName"]);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // close reader
            if (reader != null)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            // close connection
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This query exposes you to a SQL Injection attack.  Yous hould convert it to a prepared statement, however the actual error is from your use of the table name Users.  You have SELECT ... **User** which should be Users, the reason you're not getting a wrong column name error is because User is a reserved keyword and therefore SQL Server will give you that particular error unless you delimit the table name with [].  The following code should fix it.

```
string _query = "SELECT PC.SN, Users.Name + ' ' + Users.Family as AssignedTo FROM PC LEFT JOIN Users ON PC.USERID = Users.ID WHERE PC.Type = @Type";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", AssetTypeCB.SelectedItem.Value);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);
```

If your table name is actually User then this code will fix the error

```
string _query = "SELECT PC.SN, [User].Name + ' ' + [User].Family as AssignedTo FROM PC LEFT JOIN [User] ON PC.USERID = [User].ID WHERE PC.Type = @Type";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Type", AssetTypeCB.SelectedItem.ToString());
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adp.Fill(dt);
```

**More on the SQL Injection attack**

Suppose that smooene entered in your original statement the following value.

```
'; DELETE FROM Users; --
```

When you execute your SQL Statement, SQL Server will interpret it as the following:

```
SELECT PC.SN, User.Name + ' ' + User.Family as AssignedTo  
FROM PC LEFT JOIN Users ON PC.USERID = Users.ID 
WHERE PC.Type = ''; DELETE FROM Users; --'
```

This statement is completely valid and given the level of permissions your user has this can possibly delete all records from the Users table.  Using prepared statements *help* to stop that from happening.