# Retrieve Data into Combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox, textbox

This is what my [form](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?myfiles#5itvbjj1cu1112l) looks like, and my code looks like this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ProjectCSharpSQLserver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=I:\ProjectCSharpSQLserver\ProjectCSharpSQLserver\CsSQL.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into info (id, Name, phone, Address) Values ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "')", cn);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know how to open the combobox, find the Id, choose one and then then textboxes get populated by the data from the db, so I can delete and update data.

Comment: You would need to actually call the `combobox.SelectedItem` in your code, which you have yet to do.  **Also**, passing a query directly to your `SqlDataAdapter` isn't a good practice.  Learn about [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: i've tried  loop but i need a data count in a variable then i can add  items into the combobox

Comment: and yeh iam a begainner and i just need an simple ways to do things

Comment: Please post all of your relevant code then.  We here at SO are less interested in if you are a novice, intermediate or expert at coding, and much more interested in [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) in learning to code :)

Comment: i think that's all, with that code i can insert data. thats all

Comment: So what the best resource to learn what i need , i do google every day but that makes me frustrated

Comment: earlier, you mentioned that you have a `combobox` on your main form.  Where is the code for when you select the index of an item in the `combobox`?  The hyperlink you provided for the screenshot of your form doesn't work.

Comment: no no no this is the problem i need that code, then i can do somthing like X = combobox.selecteditem.string(); and query like "DELETE FROM INFO WHERE ID LIKE '"+ X +"'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an example that you can use [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx).

```
private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ComboBox cb = (ComboBox)sender;
   cn.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Place your DELETE statement here", cn);
   sda.Fill(dt);
   cn.Close();
}
```

This would run the selected statement in the `combobox` each time it is changed.  As an aside, when you run a SqlDataAdapter, it will *automatically open and close* a connection to the database for you so you don't *have* to use `cn.Open()`/`cn.Close()`.  But doing so it still a good habit to get in to.

And just to remind you, I would seriously look into using [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) once you are more comfortable with C# and ADO.NET.

Comment: Ok thanq sir i'll try this one if didn't work i'll study more about parameters

Comment: This one Solfe me the problem :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx