# NullPointerException [Object reference not set to an instance of an object]

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullpointerexception, master-pages

I have dropdownlist & button in master page, when button is clicked, I've to redirect to another page [results.aspx] that inherits the master page.
Here is a gridview to bind data according to the selected item from dropdownlist. When I try to do, it throws

> NullPointerException [Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object]

Help me with this.

This is what I did on page load event of the results.aspx.cs :

```
SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
    {
        DropDownList d1 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        DropDownList d2 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList2");
        DropDownList d3 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList3");
        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dreg where dcity='" + d2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "' && dbg='" + d3.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'", scon);
        scmd.Connection = scon;
        scon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sad = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
        SqlCommandBuilder scb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sad);
        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        sad.Fill(dTable);
        GridView1.DataSource = dTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Somewhere I heard that u ant find a previous page control if it is on master page because .net changes its id automatically. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to access **Master Page Control** so You Have to Try this :

```
DropDownList d1 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList1");
DropDownList d2 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList2");
DropDownList d3 = (DropDownList)Master.FindControl("DropDownList3");
SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dreg where dcity='" + d2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "' && dbg='" + d3.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() + "'", scon);
```

as you are accessing master Page Control. So Don't use `page.PreviousPage`.Instead You should go with `Master.FindControl` to access **Master Page Control**.

Comment: its work i have perform this ,which tye of error r u getting.let me know

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: If I remove the where condition, everything is fine & it will bind all data instead of specific. It means, it cant identify SelectedItem property of dropdown lists.

Comment: simply store  d2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() in some variable like string city= d2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString(); and than use that variable in select statement

Comment: Same Error in line: `string city = d2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();`  city& bg remains "null"

Comment: you got value in city variable or not?

Comment: The problem is only with `SelectedItem`. If I use `SelectedValue` then it does not show Exception but I get "-1" value in city or bg variables.

Comment: i dont know what happen at your side,its work perfectly in my code

Answer (score 0):

ClientIDMode ="Static", set this for the control then id should not change.

Comment: did u set results.aspx as postback url on the click event?

Comment: yes I have already set it. It redirects to the page also but the problem is, it cant identify what user selected from dropdown box.

Comment: If I remove the where condition, everything is fine & it will bind all data instead of specific.

Answer (score 0):

`FindControl` is not recursive at any level. It is unlikely that your `DropDownList` belongs to the actual Master. You will need to call `FindControl` from the panel or other control that actually has the `DropDownList`. This can become murky since your children controls in the Master are not a part of its base type, so they are not accessible through the normal properties. My recommendation would be to add a property to your master page that directly references the `DropDownList`:

```
// Do this with a unique name for each
// DropDownList you want to access
// You may have to give the property a
// a different name to prevent conflicts
public DropDownList MyDropDownList
{
    get
    {
        return MyDropDownList;
    }
}
```

Then in the pages that consume this Master page you will need to add this reference line in the html side of your page:

```
<%@ MasterType 
    virtualpath="~/Path/To/Your.master" 
%>
```

This enables the compiler to understand the specific type of the master page being referenced, so in your code behind you can access the property directly without casting:

```
DropDownList myList = Master.MyDropDownList;
```

*NOTE: Please, please, please research and begin using parameterized queries. Get in the habit of using them always, even while testing junk code. Bad habits like using inline sql have a nasty way of making it into production environments if you're not careful.*

[How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)
http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter
http://blog.divergencehosting.com/?p=71