# Updating an mdb database table

Tags: c#, .net, sql, ms-access

I'm building a simple site using .NET Web Forms and a `.mdb` database as the data source.

The problem is: I have a working backsite trough which I can create, modify and delete a new page.

While I can create and delete, the editing feature doesn't work.

I realized the problem might be in the query since the code is working fine for the other features.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE pages 
SET title=\"" + pa.title + "\" content =\"" + pa.content + "\" 
WHERE id=" + pa.id
```

I'm not very fond of SQL, am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Edit N°2. At the moment, the query is not working correctly, basically, some of the content and titles have apostrophes in them, and when i update that particular page it won't update. I tried using Regex.Escape but it creates a mess adding tons of \.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well your update query lacks a comma between fields, but that's only the tip of a big iceberg

```
UPDATE pages SET title=" + pa.title + ", content =" + pa.content + " WHERE id=" + pa.id
```

your query written in this way is exposed to a big security problem. It is called [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-this-sql-injection-work)

I will show a pseudocode because I don't have a sample of your actual code

```
string queryText = "UPDATE pages SET title=@title, content=@content WHERE id=@id"

using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryText, cn)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", pa.title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", pa.content);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", pa.id);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Working in this way you avoid problems with Sql Injection, parsing of single quotes inside your values and leaking system resource because of connection not disposed.

See
     [Parametrized Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)
     [Using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm going to rewrite the code ASAP and study SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
@"UPDATE pages 
  SET title= '" + pa.title + @"', 
      content = '" + pa.content + @"' 
  WHERE id= " + pa.id
```