# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement (Microsoft Access)

Tags: syntax, insert, ms-access-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 connected to an Access database (2010).

I created a button to add items from textboxes to the database and I'm getting the error "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"

```
    protected void upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload3.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload3.FileName);
            FileUpload3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images") + "/" + filename);
            Picture.Text = "images/" + filename;
            Label2.Text = "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Label2.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }



    }
}

protected void addnewitem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "Insert into RAM (RAM Name, picture) values ('" + name.Text.ToString() + ",'" + Picture.Text.ToString() + "')";

    AccessDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

Comment: Encapsulate the field [RAM Name] in square brackets. I think the error is due to space in the column name. "Insert into RAM ([RAM Name], picture) values"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a bit of SQL injection: append a single quote to the text you enter in the "name" textbox.

And if it works, then use parameters in your query rather than appending text from the user.

Further reading:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

[How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

**UPDATE**

Also use the correction in Alberto Spelta's comment on the original question (enclose a column name that contains spaces in brackets: "RAM Name" => "[RAM Name]").  This is another syntax error as well as the omitted single quote.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a single quote:

```
"... values ('" + name.Text.ToString() + "','" + Picture.Text.ToString() + "')"
                                          ^
```

But you shouldn't be using string concatentation like this - use a proper parameterised query instead, and you won't see these problems (or the more dangerous injection problems you get when your data contains single quotes).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
([RAM Name], picture)
```

instead of

```
(RAM Name, picture)
```

Hope this helps