# Call a function while passing strings from one form to another

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I need help to call a function while passing strings from one form to another when clicking a button.

Form1 (**Form1**) has the MySQL connection and "Select" statements needed to verify the login.

Form2 (**LoginWindow**) has the Login user and password TextBoxes and Login button.

The error I get is: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Application.Main.App.Form1.MyFunctionExposed'"

Here is what I have:

**Form1.cs:**

```
namespace Application.Main
{


  public partial class Form1 : Form 
  {
    public string strUser;
    public string strPass;

    public delegate void MyFunctionExposed();
    public static MyFunctionExposed functionMySQLCheckLogin;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        functionMySQLCheckLogin = CheckLogin(strUser, strPass);

    }




   //Check Login
   public void CheckLogin(string strUser, string strPass)
   {
       try
       {
           //Open connection
           string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = '" + strUser + "' AND user_password = '" + strPass + "' ";
           //Create Command
           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
           //Create a data reader and Execute the command and the rest of the MySQL query code


       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
  }
}
```

**Form2.cs**

```
namespace Application
{
public partial class LoginWindow : Form
    {

         public LoginWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoginWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void btnLoginGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Main.Form1.functionMySQLCheckLogin(inputBoxLoginUser.Text, inputBoxLoginPassword.Text);
        }
 }
```

Any ideas how to fix this or do it differently using these two Forms?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to compile, you just need to get the parameters correct - add the `(string, string)` signature to the delegate, and the assignment of the static is to the method group (i.e. not invoking the function):

```
    public delegate void MyFunctionExposed(string user, string pass);
    public static MyFunctionExposed functionMySQLCheckLogin;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        functionMySQLCheckLogin = CheckLogin;
    }
```

However, presumably the reason this came up is because you want to reuse the code. If so, I would consider refactoring and moving the `CheckLogin` code to a more suitable class, e.g. a common helper, data access, or even a base form class (if it is to be used by multiple forms).

Another alternative would be to make the `CheckLogin` method static (since it has no dependencies on the state of `Form1` fields) - this way you can just call it from anywhere as `Form1.CheckLogin(.., ..)`

Last thing - please look at [parameterizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) the sql query as it stands, it is susceptible to sql injection attacks, and login screens are a favourite target.