# Adding datatable row and column and updating datagridview

Tags: c#, database

```
            string conString = "Server=192.168.1.100;Database=product;Uid=newuser;Pwd=password";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conString);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            conn.Open();
            //cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            //cmd.CommandText = "Select * From tblindividualproduct";
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (txtBarcode.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Fill the correct ProductID");
                }
                else
                {
                    string sql = "Select * From tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @ProductIdText";

                    using (var adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapt)) //Not sure what you need this for unless you are going to update the database later.
                    {
                        adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductIdText", txtBarcode.Text);
                        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                        adapt.Fill(dt);
                        bs.DataSource = dt;
                        dgItems.ReadOnly = true;
                        dgItems.DataSource = bs;
                    }
                }
            }
```

How do I make the results to add, not just replace the last result. This is the whole code as requested. I just dont know if it needs manually adding of rows or there is an easy way to make it. Thank in advance

Comment: You aren't using your `BindingSource`, you assign it but never bind to it.  It should read `dgItems.DataSource = bs;`  Aside from that, do you mean you would like to add rows/columns to `dt`?

Comment: when i input 2 in my textbox it will show the product with the product id of 2 and when i want to input 3 i want it to add new row and display the product 2 and 3 in the gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should use [Parameterized SQL to avoid SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Then you just need to put the code you have in an event handler of some sort.  I would think the user would probably hit the enter key or something in the `TextBox`.

As long as you don't clear your `DataTable` it will just keep adding rows every time you run the query.  If you want to clear the table at some other point in your code just call `dt.Clear()`.

Something like this should get what you want and be safe from injection:

```
    private void txtBarCode_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBarcode.Text)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill the correct ProductID");
            } 
            else 
            {
                 string sql = "Select * From tblindividualproduct where ProductID = @ProductIdText";

                 using (var adapt = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conn))
                 using (var cmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapt)) //Not sure what you need this for unless you are going to update the database later.
                 {
                     adapt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductIdText", txtBarCode.Text);
                     BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                     adapt.Fill(dt);
                     bs.DataSource = dt;
                     dgItems.ReadOnly = true;
                     dgItems.DataSource = bs;
                 }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then make sure you have attached this event to your `TextBox` somewhere in your `Form` class like this:

```
this.txtBarCode.KeyUP += txtBarCode_KeyUp;
```

Now when the user types in the box and presses enter the query will run and the results will display in the `DataGridView`.  No need to manually add columns and rows, the `adapt.Fill(dt);` Will do that for you.

Comment: thanks for this but gridview is still updating and not adding any rows. it just only display 1 result everytime i press the enter key.

Comment: Would need to see the code where you create the `DataTable` you are probably creating the `DataTable` over and over which clears it.  You should declare it at the Class level.

Comment: @MixAustria Did you figure it out?  Just declare the `DataTable` at the class level and use it through the lifetime of the form.  Though I would recommend considering separating your data access layer from your presentation layer.

Comment: i put the DataTable at Partial class Form1

Comment: That works!  Just make sure you call `Dispose()` when you are done with it as it is unmanaged.