# "Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals varchar."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sqldatatypes

Im trying to make a code which checks my table for existing records with the same name but i am receiving an error "Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals varchar." I understand the error but i dont understand why i cant convert it into an int.

this is my code, any help to make it work will be appreciated!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection studConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            studConn.Open();
            string checkuser = "select count(*) from StudTable where-'" + TextBoxName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand studCom = new SqlCommand(checkuser, studConn);
            int temp = Convert.ToInt32 (studCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            studConn.Close();
            if (temp == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }

        }



    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid studGUID = Guid.NewGuid();

            SqlConnection studConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            studConn.Open();
            string insertQuery = "insert into StudTable (ID,Name,Email,Age,Continent,School,Password) values (@ID,@name,@email,@age,@cont,@school,@pass)";
            SqlCommand studCom = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, studConn);

            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", studGUID.ToString());
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBoxName.Text);
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", TextBoxAge.Text);
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cont", DropDownCont.SelectedItem.ToString());
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@school", TextBoxSchool.Text);
            studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", TextBoxPass.Text);

            studCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Backend.aspx");
            Response.Write("Your Registration is Sucessful");

            studConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error:" +ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to convert the value to a number, you have to explicitly make that conversion in the SQL query, or include it as a numeric literal rather than a string literal (or even better use a parameter to put the value in the query). But why would you want to convert it to a number, and what are you trying to do? The condition that you have in your `where` clause doesn't make any sense, and once you get past this error message, you would get one that tells you that a number is not a valid expression in a condition.

Comment: I wanted my code to produce 1 if a name in the table matched the one being registered, but you are right it doesnt work as i expected and im not entirely sure i understand why.

Comment: You would get for example `where-'Erademus'` in the query, when you really wanted something like `where Name = 'Erademus'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your command text and use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) instead of string concatenation

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from StudTable where Name = @Name";
SqlCommand studCom = new SqlCommand(checkuser, studConn);
studCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBoxName.Text);
```

You should remove `(-)` after `Where` and also use [*equality* operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx) `=` to check for *equality*.

Comment: Thank, this solved the error in question, i will avoid string concatenation in future.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error when making an insert command in SSMS:

I found a '-' in my sql command that I didn't realize was there (I had been putting lots of comments in my insert command in SSMS '-- and some text' after each column and had an errant minus '-' sign).  Apparently this error focuses on errant minus signs.