# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '05-04-2014 AM 12:00:00' C#?

Tags: c#, sql

AM trying to update the date in that query am getting this error Syntax error in UPDATE statement., this is my code

`Updated Code`

```
OleDbCommand top = new OleDbCommand(
         "UPDATE NewInvoice_1 SET (" +
         "Terms=?, [InvoiceDate]=?, OurQuote=?," +
         "SalesPerson=?, CustomerName=?, OrderNumber=?," +
         "InvoiceAddress=?, DeliveryAddress=?," +
         "WholeDiscountP=?, WholeDiscountA=?, ShippingP=?, ShippingA=?," +
         "Price=?, Discount=?, Tax=?," +
         "Shipping=?, GrandTotal=?, TaxforDisc=?, DiscountType=?," +
         "ShippingBy=?, ShipReferenceNo=?, IsInsured=?, Notes=?," +
         "[DueDate]=?, AmountinWords=? ) WHERE InvoiceId=?", conn);


        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_Terms.EditValue.ToString());
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_Date.DateTime);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_OurQuote.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_Sales_Person.EditValue.ToString());
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_Customer_Name.EditValue.ToString());
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Order_Number.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Invoice_Address.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Delivery_Address.Text);

        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_FlatDiscountP.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_FlatDiscountA.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_ShippingPercentage.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_ShippingAmount.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_SubTotal.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Discount.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Tax.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_Shipping.Text));
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(TXE_GrandTotal.Text));

        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", barCheckItem1.Checked);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", selectedItem);

        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Shipping_By.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Reference_No.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBX_Is_Insured.Checked);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Notes.Text);

        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_DueDate.DateTime);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_AmountinWords.Text);
        top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TXE_Unvisible.Text);
top.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now I update my code to parameters but getting Syntax error on updating code

Comment: Why you don't use parameterized query?

Comment: seriously, are you doing this?

Comment: Text and datetime values has to be string literals enclosed in quotation marks. But seriously, don't do this. Use a parameterized query. [This leaves you wide open to SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

Comment: String concatenation is not an acceptable method of constructing SQL queries from user provided data. So far your question is duplicate of many "why my query have all sorts of issues when I don't use parameterized queries" questions. If after rewriting your code to use parameter you still have a problem - please update the sample code and question will no longer be considered for duplicate.

Comment: I think your `SalesPerson` and `CustomerName` columns are character type. You might need to use `' '` their values. But please.. use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). **ALWAYS!**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for commenting guys I updated my code but still am getting syntax error. Help me to update this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameters.
Put ? for every parameter value. Use same order when adding parameter values.

```
string sql = "UPDATE NewInvoice_1 SET Terms =?, [InvoiceDate]=?, OurQuote=? ... WHERE InvoiceId=?";

            using (var command = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = sql;
                command.Parameters.Add(CBL_Terms.EditValue.ToString());
                command.Parameters.Add(CBL_Date.DateTime);
                command.Parameters.Add(TXE_OurQuote.Text);

                //add all other fields keeping order

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Side note - you shouldn't really execute or keep queries in a form.
Also, if you use adapter, you could use below syntax to add parameters:

```
command.Parameters.Add(adapter.Parameter(value));
```

Comment: Who said this is about MySQL?

Comment: Hi @AntonGorlin I updated my question please verify it

Comment: Just use Add, not AddWithValue

Comment: getting error like this `The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.`

Comment: is it the same error if you try the method you suggested? Like  top.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", CBL_Terms.EditValue.ToString());