# Stuck in C# SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Hello Every One I am new To C# and SQL can any one tell me where am I wrong. It is not inserting . And not giving any errors.

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=SHASHAK\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                             "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                             "database=Abhishek; " +
                             "connection timeout=30");

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    try
    {
        //myConnection.Open();
       //// SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select player_id, player_name , score from player", myConnection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Abhishek (" + "  player_id, player_name " + ") VALUES (" + " @textBox1.Text, @textBox2.Text", myConnection);
       SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       MessageBox.Show("Ok");

        //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        //adapter.Fill(dt);
        //screen.DataSource = dt;



    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You failed!" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you aren't executing the command, and you aren't setting your parameter values.  You commented out where you open the connection, which is pretty important

Comment: And when you do execute the command you are missing a `)` however you really really should be using [Parametrized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

Comment: [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Why VS not showing any error?

Comment: You are never executing the query, hence no error...

Comment: @AbhishekSharma because the c# code is syntactically correct but is generating invalid SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few issues with your code.

- You are trying to parameterized query but you are not passing any parameter to command
- You need to use `using` statement with your connection and command object.
- catch `System.Exception` after `SqlException` to catch any other exception.
- You are not executing your command.

Your code could be on the following lines:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=SHASHAK\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
                   "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                   "database=Abhishek; " +
                   "connection timeout=30");
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (myConnection)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO player (player_id, player_name) VALUES (@playerid, @playername)", myConnection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerid", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playername", textBox2.Text);
                myConnection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You failed!" + ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Show message / log
    }
}
```

Consider using names which reflect their values. e.g. `txtPlayerID` and `txtPlayerName` for `textBox1` and `textBox2` respectively.

Comment: `int.Parse` is not strictly nessesary, Sql will attempt to convert it for you when it performs the insert. Just be aware that it might not use your indexes in some special conditions depending on which variable (yours or the column you are doing something to) gets automatically cast.

Comment: @Habib Its giving me an error .. Invalid Object Abhishek

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, what is your table name ? is it same as your Database name ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, modified my code, your code in question had `INSERT INTO Abhishek`, it should be `INSERT INTO PLAYER`. Try the edited code in answer.

Comment: myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select player_id, player_name , score from player", myConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            screen.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, what does that code has to do with the one in question ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, if it show data, then good enough. You should see [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/yh598w02.aspx) and consider enclosing your connection and command object in `using`

Comment: Why it is showing connection property is not initialized

Comment: @AbhishekSharma, I can't really see what is going on. It should be a different question. You can ask a different question or search for the error first on Stackoverflow/google. If you can't figure out what is going on then post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Abhishek (player_id, player_name)     
             VALUES(@playerid, @playername)", myConnection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerid",textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playername",textBox2.Text);
int commandStatus = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(commandStatus > 0)
      MessageBox.Show("Row inserted Successfully!");
else
      MessageBox.Show("Row Insertion Failed!");
```

Comment: its giving error "You failed " syntax error @player"

Comment: @AbhishekSharma: sorry i missed to specify the exact parameter names , please check my edit now

Comment: giving error " must declare scaler variable @playerid"

Comment: again an error near "int commandStatus = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Comment: SQl unhandled "Incorrect syntax near '@playername'.