# Why does cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); give me error near "insert into Table..."

Tags: c#, sql

I want to create a program that save/deletes/edits database files. For example I want to enter this info to the database:

```
Name: John 
Surname: Johnson 
Father's name: Johnson 
Offers used: 10 
Age: 20
```

And all this to be saved or edited or removed. But when I try to make this

1. I can't change the database table name
2. I get this error:

   > An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
   >   Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Photography_Register
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Ivan\Documents\db.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table values('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"','"+textBox3.Text+"')";

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();           

            MessageBox.Show("Data about " + textBox1.Text + " " + textBox3.Text + " has been successfully" + "\r" + "uploaded to server!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your insert statement is wrong.    
'INSERT INTO table-name (column-names) VALUES (values)' I´m also not 100% sure if you can call your table Table.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: @Max Specifying columns is optional if you're specifying values for ALL columns.

Comment: Do you really have a table named `Table`.  If you do, you probably need to surround the name with square brackets: `insert into [Table]...`

Comment: Is your table actually named 'Table'???

Comment: @Max you can use `Table` as tablename in T-SQL, although is not recommended.

Comment: I have a table called Table and I can't change it to anything else...

Comment: I've added square brackets and it still gives me this:
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: You should use parameters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: You are supplying three text values to your Table. Does that table have exactly three columns, all of a text type? You may want to share some details about that table

Comment: When this works, try a surname of "O'Hara". Then read up on parameters

Comment: @HansKeﬆing You misspelled `;Drop Table [Table]`

Comment: I have 5 textboxes available and in the table i have 5 too. I just dont know the solution... Can someone give me a piece of code to make this work? Thank you all <3

Comment: See the comment by Max about the correct insert statement: you need to mention the columns to use

Comment: @IvanLatunov show us the names of the fields, so a correct insert can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Table` is a reserved word for T-SQL. You need to write it between `[ ]` in case it is really the name of your table.

Like this.

`insert into [Table] values` ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

**Update with parameters for the second problem (incorrect number of columns…)**

[How do I to insert data into an SQL table using C# as well as implement an upload function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301582/how-do-i-to-insert-data-into-an-sql-table-using-c-sharp-as-well-as-implement-an)

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table] (ColumnName1, ColumnName2, ColumnName3, ColumnName4, ColumnName5) VALUES (@ColumnName1, @ColumnName2, @ColumnName3, @ColumnName4, @ColumnName5)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName1", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName2", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName3", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName4", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName5", textBox5.Text);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
```

Just replace `ColumnName1` `ColumnName2`... with the name of your columns and `textBox1.Text`, `textBox2.Text`... with your input textboxes

Don't forget to cast the `textboxX.Text` to the desired datatype if the column doesn't match with `string` type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName4", int.Parse(textBox4.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ColumnName5", int.Parse(textBox5.Text));
```

Comment: Based on the data example in the question, columns 4 & 5 look like integers.

Comment: @LarsTech yes, that's why I updated my answer with the advice for a possible cast.

Comment: @blfuentes it doesnt give error now everything works fine but i cant see the info written in the dbo.Table 
Any suggestions about that?

Comment: @IvanLatunov hard to figure out why… you could check the connection string of the command to verify the `mdf` file is the one you want.

Comment: I've uploaded pics from the dbo.Table and the code. Here are the links:
https://pastebin.com/UMF21sfy
https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5592143445&photo_id=501720668220

Comment: @blfuentes thank you very much!!!!! everything is working fine i've just didn't linked the database with the datagridview but now everything is working! thanks again!!!

Comment: @IvanLatunov nice you fixed it. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it helped to resolve the issue