# SQL Insert fails with invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

When I try to fill `textbox1` with a name, I get an exception indicating an invalid column name. When I fill it with a number it works.

The datatype of `coach_name` is `varchar(50)`.

The insert code is:

```
 // connection setup code
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    string Coach_Name = textBox1.Text;
    try {        
    string Password1=textBox2.Text;
    string Password2=textBox3.Text;
    string Password=textBox2.Text;

    if (Password1.Equals(Password2))
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into CoachLogins values (" + Coach_Name + ",'" + Password + "')", conn);

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // hyi insert update delete ma btekhod shi

    }
```

Comment: **SQL injection DETECTED**

Comment: USE PARAMETRIZED QUERIES...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't wrapped `Coach_Name` in quotes, so it won't work if you pass it a string. Numeric values will work in a query like that as they don't have to be wrapped in quotes:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand _
   ("insert into CoachLogins values ('" + Coach_Name + "','" + Password + "')", conn);
```

Please read about using [parameterised queries & SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Also, I know this might be early days in your development work, but name your controls with something more useful than: `button1` and `textBox1`. It will soon become a mess if you carry on down that path.

Comment: Hi @AdelHawa, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try to turn your code like this:

Point should be Cover

1. Wrap Your Connection and Command with `**using**` which Implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. *Dont Use Plain Password*. instead of use Algorithms to encrypt it
3. Always Use [SQLParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) SQL to **AVOID SQL INJECTION**

> ```
> using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
> {
> conn.Open();
> using(SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand("insert into 
> CoachLogins (Coach_Name,Password )
>    values (@Coach_Name , @Password )", conn))
> {
> command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
> command.Parameters.Add("@Coach_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100).Value = TextBox1.Text;
> command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar,100).Value = TextBox2.Text;
> .....
>
>  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
>
> con.dispose
>
>
> }
>
> }
> ```