# Update query issue C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
string sql = "Update stdrecord set firstname='" + fname + "',lastname='" + lname + "',mobile='" + mob + "',phone='" + phn + "',city='" + city + "',province'" + prov + "'where id='" + id + "'";
```

error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax

can anybody cor rectify the query ?

Comment: use paramterised queries.

Comment: Always try your queries in your database manager first. And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: can you eloborate paramterised queries?

Comment: @user3268114 Here is an answer I wrote yesterday demonstrating parameterised queries http://stackoverflow.com/a/27247134/1663001

Comment: @user3268114 check my asnwer this is what you need for param queries.

Answer (score 8):

Your missing an equal:

`"',province = '" + prov + "' where id='" + id + "'";`

And do not build SQL-Queries like this. Please use ADO.Net Parameter.

Comment: Nice catch....! Also you should mentione OP need a white space before `WHERE` part.

Answer (score 1):

Equal sign is missing:

```
,province='" + prov + "' where id='" + id + "'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string sql = "Update stdrecord set firstname='" + fname + "',lastname='" + lname + "',mobile='" + mob + "',phone='" + phn + "',city='" + city + "',province='" + prov + "'where id='" + id + "'";
```

You miss `=` after province and there is no space between prov and `where`  !

Also in this case you are open to SqlInjection, please use SqlCommand.Parameters.

The Query should look like this.

```
string sql = @"Update stdrecord set firstname=@FName ,lastname=@LastName, mobile=@Mobile, 
               phone=@Phone,city=@City, province=@Province where id=@ID";
```

This will protect you from SqlInjection and also sql server will cache your query.

To using command Parameters you need to add this code to your `SqlCommand`

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connectionString);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FName", fName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lname );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mob);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", city);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Province", prov);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
```

With this structure you will not have problems like this in future because you will not add `+` and `'` non stop. Also use `@` when you build string this give you the possibility to write string on more than one line without using `+`.

Comment: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Article which starts this should stop and a lot of might might might. Please stop reference this, I can write everything in my blog. Also if you want to say something like that give prove ! I used AddWithValue from years and 0 problems appear, also it is used with not latin characters and nvarchars and again 0 problems. I write you that because I see you post this many times on my answers !

Comment: You are free to use it anywhere you wish, I won't downvote you for it, but I also won't upvote an answer with it in. I also used it for a long time and had no problems, but at some point, it might just come along and really bite you in the backside. I hope that doesn't happen for you. Personally I take the advice given by a Microsoft MVP seriously (after checking myself of course)

Comment: @DavidG at some point someone can nuke my country, if I don't see prove I'm not going to live in a bunker. I told you give proves with examples that the written article is correct.

Comment: The article speaks for itself and your comparison of nuclear bombs is not relevant. It's about writing solid, reliable, testable code and `AddWithName` *can* have issues. Like I said, feel free to ignore the advice, that is your choice.

Comment: Not mentioned in the article I linked is the issue of performance, some good discussion here https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e6dd040f-6bf9-4ecb-aeb1-034608472234/sql-parameters-add-vs-addwithvalue?forum=sqldataaccess

Answer (score -2):

Put a space before `Where` Clause and equal sign in province column, will get work perfectly

Comment: Yeah, this is needed also.

Comment: :) mistype only... Sorry

Comment: @SonerGönül In this case the space is NOT needed as the query engine can parse `SET x='2'WHERE blah`.

Comment: this will be not a problem like David says but show me your queris how many times you have Where written like the op. The query should be readable !