# Unhandled SqlException in user code

Tags: asp.net, database, visual-studio-2013, sqlexception, ssms

I'm trying to build a web form that can send information to a database via ASP.Net and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

[image]

[image]

It says there's incorrect syntax near Table, which is the name of the table in the database I'd like to store the values.

If you need me to post more code for clarification, I'll do that. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

I appreciate any help you can give

Thanks

EDIT:

So I changed my table name to mynameTable  and I'm getting this error.  It says string or binary data would be truncated

[image]

Comment: `Table` is a keyword in SQL. If that really is your table name, surround it with `[]`.

Comment: If that is really your table name CHANGE it, but you will soon discover that this is not your only problem here. txtFName is a textbox right?

Comment: Yeah, I named all my text box id values like that.  Like txtFName, txtEmail etc..  Why is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least four issues; two of them cause your `INSERT` statement to fail (see bold headings below), and two are design flaws (see additional suggestions under each heading below). While I listed the design flaws as "additional suggestions" only, it's actually important to fix these, too.

### 1. `TABLE` is a SQL keyword.

`TABLE` is a SQL keyword. (And so is `Table`, since SQL syntax is case-insensitive.)

If you actually named your table `Table`, you need to "escape" the name by putting it in square brackets:

```sql
INSERT INTO [Table] …
--          ^     ^
--         add these!
```

**Additional suggestion:** Change the table's name so that it hints at what kind of data or facts are stored in the table. Consider that everyone knows that `Table` is a table. But it is not obvious that `Table` contains some kind of personal data; so call your table `Customers`, `Employees`, `Hairdressers`, etc. — or if there really isn't any more specific term, call it `Persons`.

### 2. You cannot concatenate a string and a `TextBox`.

It doesn't make sense to append a `TextBox` into a string:

```cs
"… VALUES ('" + txtFName + "', …"
```

It should be:

```cs
"… VALUES ('" + txtFName.Text + "', …"
//                      ^^^^^
```

**Additional suggestion:** You are basically dynamically creating a SQL statement using string concatenation. The way how you're doing it opens up the possibility of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. (This is a kind of security hole; please research this if you don't know what it is!)

Please use parameterized queries instead:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, …) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, …)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", txtFName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", txtLName.Text);
…
```

And your SQL injection security hole is gone. Also, you won't have to worry about correctly escaping quote characters (`'`) that could have been entered by the user in the textboxes.

Comment: Thanks.  I should prolly name it something else.  I just put square brackets and it didn't work tho

Comment: @DrewKennedy: I wholeheartedly agree! I was busy editing my answer while you posted this comment.

Comment: Thanks stakx.  I'll incorporate your suggestions. Makes sense

Comment: You are doing the lord's work, sir.  Thank you so much! That was very helpful.  And yikes, I didn't realize I was vulnerable to injections :/   Thanks for the heads up

Comment: This is weird.  I followed your directions, and I was able to insert two records no problem.  Now I'm getting this error '{"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}'   I have no idea why

Comment: because one of your text columns is defined with a smaller capacity than the string's length you're trying to insert. E.g. you're inserting `"ABC"` (length 3) into a column defined as `VARCHAR(2)` (capacity 2; `"C"` will get truncated).

Answer (score 2):

Table is a keyword. You should create a new name for your table.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are using a reserved keyword `TABLE` and the first thing to do is to change that name in something more comprehensible. If you cannot change that name then you should use the square brakets around that name.

But this is just the first problem. Then you have another one.
You try to create your sql command concatenating strings but you put a textbox object in the concatenation instead of the Text property of the textbox.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [TABLE] VALUES('" + txtFName.Text + "',....
```

And **this is still very wrong** because this result in code open to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work), so what you really need to do is start using a [parameterized query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [TABLE] VALUES(@fname, @lname, ..... ");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLName.Text);
... and so on for all the others fields ....
```

Comment: I followed the directions you guys gave me, and it worked for two records, and now I'm getting an error.   This is the error '{"String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}'   Why is that?  It worked before, now all of the sudden I get this error..

Comment: It is simply a mismatch between the data length of your inputs and the data length allowed by your database fields. You should not pass more data than the database fields expect. Usually you could prevent this problem setting the MaxLength property on the user interface controls. IE _txtFName.MaxLength = <whaterSize>_ has the FirstName field.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I noticed last night.  I had varchar(10) for Credit cards, but when I put American Express, since it's more than 10 characters it didn't work.