# SQLite Search in Chinese is not working in Windows RT

Tags: sqlite, windows-8.1, windows-rt

I am writing a Windows RT app (Windows 8.1) in which I have used SQLite for the database. When I change the language setting of the machine to Chinese and I try to search a entity with a Chinese name, its returning me null even though the file exists. When the same query is used in SQLite manager, it returns back the respective entity.
Code used :

```
var q = string.Format("SELECT Entity.* from Entity where upper(Name) like '%{0}%' or upper(Keywords) like '%{1}%' ", queryString, queryString);
            return db.Query<Entity>(q);
```

The letter could be "啊"

The search is working fine in English. So, do we have to enable something while installing to allow multilingual operation? or any extra parameter need to be sent to indicate that the language is different while sending a query?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to format the string as UTF-8/Unicode. [Suggested reading re internationalization](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

I don't know what language you're using (C# I'm guessing), but using parameterized queries might help get around encoding issues, and [it looks pretty simple to change to](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/09/using-parameters-parameterized-queries-database-interactions-cshar-vbnet/). Bonus points for avoiding SQL Injection (See [How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)) It's a local app, so not *too* serious... but still, bad practice.

Comment: Actually, I am using the similar code for Windows Phone and the query is working fine. I am getting the expected results. But while working in Windows RT device, the query is not providing the expected result. The libraries for them are separately compiled. Is there anything to be done while compiling it to support malti-language?