# Issue with getting state of check box in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to help me someone this checkboxs in C#. I don't know how to get the state of the check box. I will send the code to see if someone can help me with this. I want to make an Insert in the database, my query work pretty well when i test it directly in the database, and now I can't find solution for this, if any one can help me will be great.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Program_Sistem_Menaxhimi_Per_Gjykatat
{
    public partial class AddNewEmploee : Form
    {
        public AddNewEmploee()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void createUserAddNewEmploeeButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void confirmAddNewEmploeeButt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=fp-PC;Initial Catalog=Gjykata;Integrated Security=True";//Connection String
            string sqlcommand = "insert into Puntoret (emri,mbiemri,adresa,telefoni,id_profesionit,isUser,isAdmin,username,passWord) values ('" + emriTextBox.Text + "','" + mbiemriTxtBox.Text + "','" + adresaTxtBox.Text + "','" + telefoniTxtBox.Text + "','" + idEProfTxtBox.Text + "','" + checkBoxUser.ThreeState.ToString() + "','" + checkBoxAdmin.ThreeState.ToString() + "','" + usernameTxtBox.Text + "','" + passwordTxtBox.Text + "')";//Sql command
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);//Creating new Sql Connetion

            if(emriTextBox.Text != "" && mbiemriTxtBox.Text != "" && adresaTxtBox.Text != "" && telefoniTxtBox.Text != "" && idEProfTxtBox.Text != "" && checkBoxUser.ThreeState.ToString() != "False" && checkBoxAdmin.ThreeState.ToString() != "False" && usernameTxtBox.Text != "" && passwordTxtBox.Text != "")
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlcommand))
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = sqlcommand;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides wondering why you're adding new butts to "emploees", where is the attempt to read the state of the checkbox? ... butt transplants?

Comment: Use the `Checked` property? ie `checkBox1.Checked`. Returns `true` when checked and `false` when unchecked.

Comment: The `Checked` property is what you are looking for [ToggleButton.IsChecked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection to change your sql code.

Comment: Why you didn't use `checkBoxUser.Checked==True` ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ThreeState

```
checkBoxUser.Checked.ToString();
```

will return "true" or "false"

Answer (score 0):

I will thank you all for your answers but I implement another solution and I think it's is better because in my database in table Puntoret(Emploees) i have two colones wich are isUser and isAdmin end those two colones at 'bit' data type wich return true or false. My implementation is in the query i write:
checkBoxUser ?  '1' '0' 
checkBoxAdmin ? '1' '0'

And in my "if statemen" is without checkBoxes. Now I'm answer to you from mobile device.. when i will have my laptop I will send full code. 
But again thank you all.