# Breakpoint in Acces Database Application C#

Tags: c#, exception

I get syntax error when i try to run and insert data in my database.... i have a log in button and delete button that works just fine.... but this one does not and i don't get it..... Can some one tell me an alternative to insert or what is the mistake?

```
public partial class Register : Form
    {
        private OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection();
        public Register()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            connect.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=resources\Users.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
        }
    private void register1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;
            command.CommandText ="insert into Users(Username, Password, Email)  values(' " + userR_box.Text + " ',' " + passwordR_box.Text + " ',' " + mailR_box.Text + " ')";
                            if ((userR_box.Text == "") || (passwordR_box.Text == "") || (mailR_box.Text == ""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Va rugam completati toate campurile");
            }
            else
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error "+ ex);
        }
        connect.Close();
    }
```

Comment: could you add the error trace?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, read up on adding parameters to your query, on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or Stack Overflow ([How do parameterized queries help against SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)).

It will save you building a string and maybe getting quotes in the wrong place.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code i noticed 3 things:

- You have extra space before every value `' " + userR_box.Text + " '`
- Its not clear what is the data that you are trying to insert, if it contains `'` or any other char which might affect the query ... this will cause the error.
- Password is reserved keyword, use this `INSERT into Users ([Username], [Password], [Email]...` to avoid reserved keywords.