# prevent escape string c#

Tags: c#, sql, escaping

I have my sql query which displays fields using "where" from a variable.
I have my variable passed from a function

**string** empCode which value is "**!\\(**"

Here's my code:

```
public List<int> GetSuccessAndFailedCountForTodayForAgent(string empCode)
{
     var result = new List<int>();
     string query = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BusinessTransactions WHERE STATUS='Failed' AND ENTEREDDATE='" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString() + "' AND AgentEmployeeCode='" + empCode + "') AS FAILED_COUNT, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BusinessTransactions WHERE STATUS='Completed' AND ENTEREDDATE='" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString() + "' AND AgentEmployeeCode='" + empCode  + "') AS SUCCESS_COUNT";
     using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(asynchPaymentDBConnectionString))
     {
          conn.Open();
          using (SqlCommand s = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
          {
               using (SqlDataReader reader = s.ExecuteReader())
               {
                    try
                    {
                         if (reader.HasRows)
                         {
                               while (reader.Read())
                               {
                                    result.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                                    result.Add(reader.GetInt32(1));
                               }
                         }
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                         //do something
                   }
               }
          }
     }
     return result;
}
```

In my C# the result becomes 0 - 0 which when i try to sql server directly it display a result of 2 - 0

The string **!\\(** is being treated as **!\(**

How can I use my string **!\\(** to my where clause?

**EDIT:**

I tried using parameters adding:

```
s.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16);
s.Parameters["@EmployeeCode"].Value = empCode;
```

Still doesn't work

Comment: Try parameterizing your query.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Like @FelixPamittan suggested, you should use [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build your query instead of just concatenating strings.

Comment: Linked as duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection question explains what is SQL injection and shows how to fix it (which will also solve your issue you are trying to hack around)

Comment: Aside from parameterizing your code, you can add `@` in front strings to tell compiler to ignore escape chars.

Comment: using parameters doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

To escape a backslash in C# string you can either use a double backslash or prefix the entire string with @ which will treat the string literally and escape all characters.

I.e.

```
@"foo!\(bar"
```

will produce the string

```
foo!\(bar
```

You can only do this when you are assigning the string to the variable, you can't prefix a variable with @.

Comment: How can I do it when it is from a variable?

I tried string id = @empCode and use id instead but doesn't work also

Comment: You would need to use this to assign the string to the variable but you don't need to do it again when using the variable.

Comment: Also isn't empCode the string being passed in? In which case you need to put the @ in front of the string when it's assigned to empCode, wherever that is done. You can't retrospectively escape characters.