# Incorrect syntax near '79000'

Tags: c#, .net

I have this comamand and that error, in data i have zip code 79000 and table name site

```
   private void Crt_clck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CMC, [Site Name], [Phone Number], Zip_Code FROM site Where Zip_Code'" + Zipcode.Text + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            con.Close();
        }
```

can you help me with this

Comment: `Zip_Code'" + Zipcode.Text + "'"` should be `Zip_Code='" + Zipcode.Text + "'"`?  However, these should be a paramaterized.

Comment: where Zip_Code = 79000? Seriously...

Comment: I vote to close this question due a simple typo, a forgotten `=`

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries read more here, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlphp/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection

Comment: WHERE Zip_Code = '" + Zipcode.Text + "'

Comment: tnx guys i  just forget to use = not my self this days tnx again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your sql statement to

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CMC, [Site Name], [Phone Number], Zip_Code FROM site Where Zip_Code = '" + Zipcode.Text + "'";
```

You are missing the = which is needed for the syntax to be correct.

But you should think about using parameter instead to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

[Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements) could be interesting for this, too.

Comment: Following this logic I should have added EF or NHibernate...

Comment: @MightyBadaboom no EF needed, just use parameter to guard against a user inputting a quote (and maybe extra sql statements - `'; drop table site; --`).

Comment: I know about SQL injection and why and how you should avoid it. Edited my post to let the author know about this, too. I just don't understand why someone downvoting questions when the answer does what the questioner wants. You can always refactoring the code of the questioner to make it better. But that would not help a lot.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote this answer.

Comment: @DavinTryon thx :)