# How to exploit a SQL injection inside "IN" condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to exploit the following sql (in SQL Server 2014):

```
declare @maliciousSQL nvarchar(max);
set @maliciousSQL = '???'
exec ('SELECT SUM(quantity) from mytable where id in ' + @maliciousSQL );
```

How can parameter @maliciousSQL be crafted to run any arbitrary sql? Assume the task is to execute command 'truncate table othertable' - is it doable?

Thanks to anyone for help

Comment: As far as i know, IN has to refer to a dataset with 1 column, so don't think that can be done. Though there might be workarounds

Comment: @Kevin Sijbers I am exactly after a 'workaround' solution. Can some block of SQL be executed after the "IN" condition and then, say, execute SELECT 1,2,3 to behave like normal? The latter is not important really. Most important is to execute some evil code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Injection looks like this:

```
declare @maliciousSQL nvarchar(max);
set @maliciousSQL = '(1); DELETE test1;'
exec ('SELECT SUM(quantity) from mytable where id in ' + @maliciousSQL );
```

Terminate the statement with a semicolon then write what you like

Comment: I'll mark Ruben's reply as correct answer, because he gave it one minute earlier, but thank you very much

Comment: @lekso, actually looks like Nick came before a few seconds; give it to him ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
set @maliciousSQL = '(1);  truncate table XXX;'
```

The entire point is to do not concatenate SQL statements and preferring to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Actually, the question title is misleading: you **can't** run DDL *inside* a DML statement, but a malicious caller can run multiple separate commands if you allows unsafe concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up the SQL *before* executing.  I also recommend `sp_executesql`.  So:

```
declare @maliciousSQL nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @maliciousSQL = '???'
set @sql = 'SELECT SUM(quantity) from mytable where id in ' + @maliciousSQL;

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Sorry, I might have been wrong describing my task. My question was:  How should @maliciousSQL parameter look like in order to execute a 'truncate table ..." command?