# I get this error when running my program i debug: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Login'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to construct a log in using the SqlServer which I'm not so familiar with. I don't ask for a very precise answer but more of a point in a general direction where the error may be. Should I learn more about the SqlServer to solve this problem or is the error somewhere else?

```
namespace Log_in
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Joel\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Login WHERE Username='" + tbxLogIn.Text + "'AND Password ='"+tbxPassword.Text+"'", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Main ss = new Main();
                ss.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect log in details.");
            }
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should *definitely* learn more about working with SQL. For one thing, parameterized queries are king. Your query as it stands it vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Check out https://xkcd.com/327/ for the horrors.

Comment: For your immediate error problem, it looks like you don't have a table called Login in your database.

Comment: I fixed the first problem by changing Login to Table but now a second one appears: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

Answer (score 1):

1. That error means it's not seeing `Login`. Either the table isn't there or you need to access it via schema.
2. This code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. **Please** learn about parameterized queries or use something like Entity Framework. [More Info on how parameterized queries solves the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Comment: I fixed the first problem by changing Login to Table but now a second one appears: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'