# Can I condense this if statement?

Tags: c#, sql

```
if (allStatusCheckBox.Checked != true)
{
  if (assComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && revComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
    dataSda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DATAACTUALID WHERE ASSIGNEDSTATUS LIKE '" + statusComboBox.SelectedValue + "' AND A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_ID LIKE '" + assComboBox.SelectedValue + "%' AND A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_ID LIKE '" + revComboBox.SelectedValue + "%'", patientCon);
  }
  else if (assComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1 && revComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
  {
    dataSda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DATAACTUALID WHERE ASSIGNEDSTATUS LIKE '" + statusComboBox.SelectedValue + "' AND A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_ID LIKE '" + assComboBox.SelectedValue + "%'", patientCon);
  }
  else if (assComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1 && revComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
  {
    dataSda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DATAACTUALID WHERE ASSIGNEDSTATUS LIKE '" + statusComboBox.SelectedValue + "' AND A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_ID LIKE '" + revComboBox.SelectedValue + "%'", patientCon);
  }
  else
  {
    dataSda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DATAACTUALID WHERE ASSIGNEDSTATUS LIKE '" + statusComboBox.SelectedValue + "'", patientCon);
  }       
}
else
{
    //REPEAT WITHOUT STATUSCOMBOX.SELECTED VALUE
}
```

Basically the point of this code is to display some information based on whether certain filters have been applied. However with my current approach every time I apply a new filter my number of if statements is growing exponentially. I am worried my code will soon become slow and hard to manage as I apply more filters. Is there a better way of achieving the same results?

Comment: Your C# code/query code is not remotely legible.  I recommend just showing enough if branches to get the point across.  And please wrap those queries so that they are completely visible without scrolling.

Comment: *I am worried my code will soon become slow* An if statement can't be sped up. This code is not going to be a performance bottleneck

Comment: First off, you have a lot of repeated code.  Secondly, you have glaring SQL injection vulnerabilities.  I would address both of those things first and I bet you will find your actual question answered in the process

Comment: @Liam: true, nevertheless the "hard to manage" argument is valid.

Comment: Sorry will format my code to become more legible.

Comment: `assComboBox`: nice naming XD

Comment: @Person I would also strongly consider moving these queries into stored procedures instead of letting all this SQL sit inside, and be maintained in C#

Comment: I agree with @maccettura on that one: the argument that's it's hard to manage is mainly because your naming can be improved. Things like `assComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1` doesn't explain it's meaning on it's own and makes it hard to read. If it would say: `IsAssSelected`, it would be clearer (although it still could be improved).

Comment: worry more about the SQL injection; the performance of a few `if`s is **irrelevant** compared to a round-trip to a database server

Comment: If you used an ORM like EF you could dynamically build the query which could make the code more manageable.

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'm still very new to OOP and using sql so forgive me. I will research the concerns you have all raised. I appreciate you guys taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few *bigger* problems to worry about with your code before worrying about some `if` statements.  I will address all of those and you will start to see that fixing them, will fix your mess.

First, your SQL query text is *basically* the same across all of your queries:

```
SELECT 
    DATAACTUALID, 
    A_DATAACTUAL.TRIGGERPOINTSID, 
    TBLPT.PT_ID, 
    NAME as C, 
    A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_ID as ASSIGNEDID, 
    A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_ID as REVIEWERID, 
    TBLPT.LASTNAME + ' ' + TBLPT.FIRSTNAME as Patient, 
    TRIGGERNAME as DESCRIPTION, 
    TRIGGERPOINTNAME as DETAIL, 
    A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_LASTNAME + ' ' + A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_FIRSTNAME as Assigned, 
    TODOBY, A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_LASTNAME + ' ' + A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_FIRSTNAME as Reviewer, 
    REVIEWDATE, 
    GRADE, 
    COMMENT 
FROM A_DATAACTUAL 
    INNER JOIN TBLPT ON A_DATAACTUAL.PT_ID = TBLPT.PT_ID 
    INNER JOIN A_TRIGGERPOINTS ON A_DATAACTUAL.TRIGGERPOINTSID = A_TRIGGERPOINTS.TRIGGERPOINTSID 
    INNER JOIN A_TRIGGERS ON A_TRIGGERPOINTS.TRIGGERID = A_TRIGGERS.TRIGGERID 
    INNER JOIN A_ASSIGNEDTO ON A_DATAACTUAL.ASSIGNEDTO = A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_ID 
    INNER JOIN A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY ON A_DATAACTUAL.TOBEREVIEWEDBY = A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_ID 
    INNER JOIN A_STATUS ON A_DATAACTUAL.ASSIGNEDSTATUS = A_STATUS.STATUSID
```

You see all those joins and specific selects/aliases?  This is a *prime* opportunity to create a SQL View, then you can query that newly created View instead of constantly doing the same exact query over and over again.

Lets say you named the view `v_SomeView`, all your queries would look like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM v_SomeView WHERE A_ASSIGNEDTO.EMP_ID LIKE ..."

"SELECT * FROM v_SomeView WHERE A_TOBEREVIEWEDBY.EMP_ID LIKE ..."
```

Use the power of SQL, C# should only be responsible for so much...

Second huge problem is you have SQL Injection vulnerabilities.  You should **never** concatenate SQL queries like this.  **Always use parameters**.

A quick example if you must use `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
dataSda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM v_SomeView WHERE ASSIGNEDSTATUS = @someValue", patientCon);
dataSda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@someValue", assComboBox.SelectedValue));
```

With these two changes you have made your code more secure, you have kept it DRY and you leveraged the power of SQL.

Comment: Its good that I am learning these lessons now. So as I understand it without using parameters someone could potentially input a string that would modify my sql statement to allow them to insert or modify records or a number of other things. With parameters the statement would just treat that input as a value to search. I still can't fully wrap my head around how parameters prevent injection, but I guess that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @Person You are correct with what you are understanding, as for why a good Stack Overflow question detailing why parameters work the way they do can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection).

Comment: Ok I think I fully understand now. Parameters prevent the possibility of escaping the select statement by using characters like ; and then writing your own sql statement. Instead the parameters treat these characters as part of the parameter. Thanks for all your help.