# C# Fill Datagridview Between 2 Datetimepicker selected value

Tags: c#, winforms

Below these code is what i've tried to achieve these but unfortunately i failed to do that, that's why i'm here. I really need help guys in solving these problem of mine.

Expected Output:
If user select a date between two datetimepicker, for example is from Sep 1 to Sep 21, so the row with the date of Sep 1 to 21 will be only displayed.

Nothing Happens here below these code.

NOTE:

- DateReturn and DateReturn2 is both datetimepicker, the first one is DateReturn

  ```
  public partial class SIMSSupplier : UserControl
  {
  ADDSupplier supply;
  ADDPReturns returns;
  public SIMSSupplier()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

  }
  public DataTable dbdataset;
  public void CustomDatetime()
  {
      var now = DateTime.Now;
      var first = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
      var last = first.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
      DateReturn.Value = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, 1);
      DateReturn2.Value = last;
  }
  public void ReturnDetails()
  {
      FillSupplier(PurchaseReturn, "Select ReturnID, Supplier, Itemdescription, Modelno, Srp, Code, Date, Remarks from Purchase_Return");
  }
  private void FillSupplier(DataGridView grid, string request)
  {
      using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
      using (var select = new SqlCommand(request, con))
      using (var sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
          dbdataset = new DataTable();
          sda.SelectCommand = select;
          sda.Fill(dbdataset);
          grid.DataSource = new BindingSource() { DataSource = dbdataset };
          sda.Update(dbdataset);
      }
  }
   private void SIMSSupplier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {           
      ReturnDetails();
      CustomDatetime();
   }
   private void DateReturn2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
      {
          using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select * from Purchase_Return where Date between '" + DateReturn.Value.ToString() + "' and '" + DateReturn2.Value.ToString() + "'", con))
          {
              using (var sd = new SqlDataAdapter(select))
              {
                  var dv = new DataView(dbdataset);
                  PurchaseReturn.DataSource = dv;
              }
          }
      }
   }
  }
  ```

[image]
I tried to select Sept 22, but nothing happen

Comment: have you debug on  `DateReturn2_ValueChanged` ? and see what is the content of `dv` ?. i think you need to initialized new datatable instead of using dataView. or  if you don't want to intiatlized new datatable, try to clear dbdataset before hand

Comment: @chopperfield I tried to debug it, dv is null. Can you elaborate your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this 100% correct, but the main idea is try using new datatable to set it as datasource

```
private void DateReturn2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    using (var con = SQLConnection.GetConnection())
    {
         using (var select = new SqlCommand("Select * from Purchase_Return where Date between @date1 and @date2", con))
        {
            select.Parameters.Add("@date1",SqlDbType.Date).value= DateReturn1.Value;
            select.Parameters.Add("@date2",SqlDbType.Date).value= DateReturn2.Value;

            using (var sd = new SqlDataAdapter(select))
            {                    
                DataTable newDT= new DataTable();
                sd.selectcommand = select;
                sd.fill(newDT);
                //PurchaseReturn.DataSource = null;
                PurchaseReturn.DataSource = newDT;        
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Downvoted - because you aren't using parameters in your answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163361/how-can-i-add-user-supplied-input-to-an-sql-statement - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection - and many more links

Comment: @RandRandom Really ?,  that's more like suggestion dude. iam just try to give him an idea/concept to solved his problem

Comment: @RandRandom by doing so, you are discourage people to give an Answer, Comment instead of downvoting

Comment: Yes, really. It's that big of a problem, not a single developer on this whole world should ever ever concat parameters by string and always use parameters - you never want to face the same problems as Bobby faces - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: @RandRandom There you go ~

Comment: Fixed it for ya.

Comment: Addwithvalue is not recommend in using parameters, downvoted you should give him a proper way. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/