# sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: None

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

Can Anyone Help Me to Fix This Problem This is my code why it can't detect the column?
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: None

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


    def Daftar():
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Welcome to TutorialsPoint")
    window.geometry('400x400')
    window.configure(background = "grey");

    Lnpm = Label(window, text="Please Input Your npm: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
    Lnama = Label(window,text="Please Input Your nama: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
    Ljurusan = Label(window,text="Please Input Your jurusan: ").grid(row=2, column=0)

    npm1 = Entry(window).grid(row = 0,column = 1)
    nama1 = Entry(window).grid(row = 1,column = 1)
    jurusan1 = Entry(window).grid(row = 2,column = 1)

    def Clicked():
     npm = npm1
     nama = nama1
     jurusan = jurusan1

     connect = sqlite3.connect('C:///Users///Marvin///Desktop///FaceRecognition-Presernsi-sql///SQL///Presensi.db')
     cur = connect.cursor()
     connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user(npm,nama,jurusan) Values("+str(npm)+",' "+str(nama)+" ',' "+str(jurusan)+" ' )")
     connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO presensi(nama) Values(' "+str(nama)+" ')")
     connect.commit()
     cur.close()
    tn = ttk.Button(window ,text="Register",command=Clicked).grid(row=3,column=0)
```

Comment: Are you sure the columns `npm, nama, jurusan` exist in table `user` and `nama` in table `presensi`? These look are the values, not the column names.

Comment: yes that exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following columns actually exist in the table `user`: `npm, nama, jurusan`; and in table `presensi`: `nama`.

> ```
> connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user(npm,nama,jurusan) Values("+str(npm)+",' "+str(nama)+" ',' "+str(jurusan)+" ' )")
> connect.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO presensi(nama) Values(' "+str(nama)+" ')")
> ```

If you are trying to update text columns like this you have to surround the values with *quotes*, i.e. it should be `...values('" + str(npm) + "'"...`

However, building the sql query like this leads to the possibility of sql injection attacks. It's better to use [parameterised queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection) instead, using placeholders:

```
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO user(npm,nama,jurusan) values(?,?,?)", (str(npm),str(nama),str(jurusan))
cur.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO presensi(nama) values(?)", (str(nama),))
```

Comment: this is fix but why the output is none from                                                                       
     `npm = npm1`
     `nama = nama1`
     `jurusan = jurusan1`

Comment: @marvinarieljohannes I'm not sure if `npm1`, `nama1` and `jurusan1` are global variables? If they only exist in function `Daftar()` then they will be `None`. I think you should pass them into the function like this: `def Clicked(npm, nama, jurusan):`